# Means Between Groups in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to get the mean and sd between groups in my dataframe with no success.

It is easier to explain with an example.

```
sample <- c("CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1") 
test <- c("AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS", "AS") 
replicate <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b")
xvalue <- c(1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1)
moduli<- c("G1", "G2", "G1", "G2", "G1", "G2", "G1", "G2", "G1", "G2", "G1", "G2" ) 
yvalue <- c(12, 15, 34, 23, 23, 23, 54, 23, 24, 21, 12, 11)

df <- data.frame(sample, test, replicate, moduli, xvalue, yvalue)


obs. sample test replicate moduli xvalue yvalue
1      CT   AS         a     G1      1     12
2      CT   AS         a     G2      1     15
3      CT   AS         a     G1      2     34
4      CT   AS         a     G2      2     23
5      CT   AS         b     G1      1     23
6      CT   AS         b     G2      1     23
7      X1   AS         a     G1      1     54
8      X1   AS         a     G2      1     23
9      X1   AS         a     G1      2     24
10     X1   AS         a     G2      2     21
11     X1   AS         b     G1      1     12
12     X1   AS         b     G2      1     11
```

What I need to do is group by `sample`, `test`, `moduli` and get the means and sd of `yvalue` between `replicate`. So in this example, that would be the mean and sd between `obs.` 1 and 5, 2 and 6, 7 and 11, 8 and 12.

I'm guessing that it is possible to achieve this using `aggregate` and `dplyr`, but have had no success so far.

Thank you!!

Comment: Hi Lucas. What you want to do is not quite clear. Can you show us how your desired output looks like?

Comment: Agree this is unclear. What does it mean to "get the means and sd of yvalue between `replicate`"? Is `replicate` just another grouping variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the mean of `yvalue` across observations `1` and `5` because the belong to the same group regarding the grouping variables you have mentioned and `xvalue` as well and similarly, observations `2` and `6`, ... etc. If this is the case, you will need to include `xvalue` as a grouping variable as well

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(sample, test, moduli, xvalue) %>% 
  summarise(mean.y = mean(yvalue),
            sd.y = sd(yvalue))
# A tibble: 8 x 6
# Groups:   sample, test, moduli [?]
  sample test  moduli xvalue mean.y   sd.y
  <fct>  <fct> <fct>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 CT     AS    G1          1   17.5   7.78
2 CT     AS    G1          2   34   NaN   
3 CT     AS    G2          1   19     5.66
4 CT     AS    G2          2   23   NaN   
5 X1     AS    G1          1   33    29.7 
6 X1     AS    G1          2   24   NaN   
7 X1     AS    G2          1   17     8.49
8 X1     AS    G2          2   21   NaN
```

This will calculate the mean across different `replicate` within a group. But SD cannot be computed unless you have more than one observation in the group.

Comment: Hi Adballah, the code you provided appears to be working and i thank you for that.    The problem is that my `xvalue` is a continuous variable and i need to plot them in a XY scatter plot. The `replicate` variable are different batches of my sample and i need to plot the mean as a line and sd as an error bar between those batches.

Comment: So, why did you say you want the average between `1` and `5` not `3` and `5`. Why not averaging across `1` and `3` and `5`. What is the role here?

Comment: I don't want the average between `1`, `3` and `5` because the `xvalue` is different in `3`. I understand that to use `group_by()` to get the expected result I need to use `xvalue` as a categorical variable but when I plot the graph it can't be. It needs to be an continuous variable. I tryed achieving this with `as.numeric()` but it didn't work properly.

Comment: You can actually `group_by()` a continuous variable and plot with it as well. You don't need to convert `xvalue` neither for grouping nor for plotting. How many unique values of `xvalue` does your data have? you can check by `length(unique(df$xvalue))`

Comment: It currently has 245 unique values, but if i don't have to "factorize" them i think it solves the problem. I'll have to test with the real data but so far it sems to be working